# Angular JS getting a value to appear in an input text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this value here:

```
{{step1.$valid}}
```

which returns false. What I am trying to do is get the text "false" to appear in an input text box:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.stepValidation" ng-value="{{step1.$valid}}"/>
```

I have also tried value and ng-bind and neither of these get the value from {{step1.$valid}} to appear in my input text...please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.stepValidation.step1.$valid"/>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p97m4/).

Comment: `{{step1.$valid}}` is generated from `<form name="step1" novalidate>` how would I assign it to `$scope.user.stepValidation.step1.$valid`

Comment: I could not do this `$scope.user.stepValidation = { step1: {{step1.$valid}} };`

Comment: So many questions... First, update your question to include the broader scope of your problem. Second, why do you need to add a text box that holds the value of the validity of your form?? So you can type in "true"? LOL this should be a read-only value. Also, when you name a form, it's available on the encapsulating scope e.g. `$scope.step1`.